# Disable edit text field in android for 30 seconds

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a login screen for an android app. If a user enter wrong password credential 3 times, then the edit text field will be disable for 30 second. After 30 seconds, user can input their password again. How can i achieve it? Thank you

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
//Disable your EditText
Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();
handlerTimer.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
          // Enable it        
      }}, 30000);
```

But I think it's not a good solution to block an edit text 30 seconds, why would you do that?

I hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

Thanks to @ridsatrio, I have UPDATED the code.

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     editText.setEnabled(true);
 }
}.start();
```

Comment: This is rather inefficient. The `onTick()` will always be called, thus calling unnecessary `editText.setEnabled(false)`, throughout the time set. One call to `setEnabled(false)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you'll have to have a counter that increments every time a wrong password is submitted. A simple `int` field would do the trick:

```
int passwordAttempt = 0;
```

Next, you'll have to increment this "counter" when a user has entered a wrong password. If the counter reaches 3, disable your `EditText` (and re-enable it after 30 seconds):

```
if(passwordAttempt == 3) {
  // User has entered wrong password 3 times.

  // Disable your EditText.
  yourEditText.setEnabled(false);

  // Re-enable your EditText after 30000 milliseconds (30 seconds).
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      yourEditText.setEnabled(true);
    }
  }, 30 * 1000);

  // Reset the counter.
  passwordAttempt = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int start1=18000;

final Timer timer = new Timer();

new Thread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
               @Override
               public void run() {

                  activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                        if (start1 <= 0) {
                           timer.cancel();
                           timer.purge();
                           editTextActivation.setEnabled(true);
                        }

                        start1 = start1 - 1000;
                     }
                  });
               }
            }, 0, 1000);
         }
      }).start();
```